# Same Code different Variables - don't work

Tags: javascript

So I am just trying different things with JavaScript and my question is really embarrassing but I have the same code with two different variables but one function does work the other doesn't:

```
    <button onclick="incA(1)">Increment A!</button>
    <br />
        a: <span id="a">0</span>
    <br />
<button onclick="incB(1)">Increment B!</button>
    <br />
        b: <span id="b">0</span>
```

and this is the JavaScript:

```
    var a = 0;

function incA(number){
    a = a + number;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
}
var b = 0;

function incB(number){
    b = b + number;
    document.getElementByID("b").innerHTML = b;
}


window.setInterval(function(){

    incA(1);
    incB(1);

}, 100);
```

Increment a on interval and by button works perfectly fine. B just stays at 0 and the button doesn't increment it either.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: change `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById`

Comment: you edited your first typo i wanted to mention, but you still have one in here: `document.getElementByID("b").innerHTML = b;`

Comment: Your browser console is telling you the problem.  And it's telling it to you 10 times per second.

Comment: Oh my god this is really embarassing... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your line

```
document.getElementByID("b").innerHTML = b;
```

There is no function `document.getElementByID`; the proper spelling is [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) with a final lower-case *d*. Like virtually all programming languages, JavaScript is case-sensitive.

To detect this and other errors, use the developer tools of your browser, and look at the *errors* or *console* tab. For instance, with Chrome you can press <kbd>F12</kbd>, you'll see an error message like
[image: Chrome developer tools]

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` not `getElementByID`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case case sensitive

```
  document.getElementByID("b").innerHTML = b;

  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b;
```